# Duplicate the samples in a dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining, sampling

I use the code to check my dataset 'df' and see serious imbalance in column 'Has_Arrears'. I would expand my target dataset with duplicate samples under Has_Arrears = 1 35 times. i.e. sample 35 times for each observation of Has_Arrears = 1. How can I achive this? Cheers

If I would like to use stratify sampling, how can I code for this?

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly you want in this question. What sort of object do you need your code to return? Is it an array of indices which represent the oversampled rows where Has_Arrears == 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this may be what you're looking for:

```
new = df['Has_Arrears'] == 1
a = df[new]
df = df.append([a]*35, ignore_index=True)
```